# SQL - result of Stored Procedures

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I have two tables and A and B and i have a third table with result of join A and B,i use mariadb database, i want to store result in the third table result_A_B but I have this message when i run "CALL session_cpu_procedure()": ERROR 1136 (21S01): Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

```
CREATE TABLE result_A_B (
ID INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
cid nvarchar(100) NOT NULL, 
time datetime NOT NULL,
OS nvarchar(100) NOT NULL, 
program nvarchar(100) NOT NULL,
nb_OS_by_program FLOAT NOT NULL,
cpu FLOAT,
last_line int NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
UNIQUE KEY (`cid`,`time`,`program`) ) ENGINE=InnoDB;


DELIMITER |
CREATE PROCEDURE session_cpu_procedure()
BEGIN
TRUNCATE result_session_cpu_CPLSVFX201P;
INSERT INTO result_session_cpu_CPLSVFX201P
SELECT DISTINCT C.cid,  C.time, C.OS, C.program, COUNT(*) as nb_OS_by_program, O.cpu, C.last_line 
FROM session_test C LEFT outer JOIN cpu_test O ON O.sid2 = C.cid and O.time = C.time and C.PROGRAM=O.MODULE 
where C.time
GROUP BY C.time, C.OS, C.program, C.last_line;
END |
DELIMITER ;

CALL session_cpu_procedure();
```

I want to know how to resolve this error: ERROR 1136 (21S01): Column count doesn't match value count at row 1, thanks for any response

Comment: If you are not inserting into every column (and you aren't inserting to id) then you have to include the column names you are inserting to in the insert statement. Even if the the id column is auto_increment, 'If you do not specify a list of column names for INSERT ... VALUES or INSERT ... SELECT, values for every column in the table must be provided by the VALUES list or the SELECT statement' -https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert.html

Answer (score 2):

You have a table with 8 columns.

Your `SELECT... INSERT` statement has 7 columns.

This generated the rather self explanatory error.

Option 1:

Since you have a UNIQUE key already, make this the primary key and remove the AUTO_INCREMENT column.

Option 2:

Be explicit in your `INSERT SELECT` about the columns omitting the auto_increment column:

```
INSERT INTO result_session_cpu_CPLSVFX201P
  (cid, time, OS, program, nb_OS_by_program, CPU, lastline)
SELECT ....
```